# Выборка объявления с условием?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите как составить запрос mysql.
Если значение поля "SHOW_ALL" в базе данных != 1, тогда запрос (COUNTRY_ID = 10 && CITY_ID = 2), если "SHOW_ALL" = 0, тогда ""

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE SHOW_ALL = 1 OR (COUNTRY_ID = 10 && CITY_ID = 2)
```